# Using WebDav & RoboCopy to copy docs between Document Libraries

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint-2013, webdav, robocopy

I am trying to automate the process of copying documents between SharePoint 2013 document libraries using a RoboCopy job which calls WebDav.

Batch only works if first manual connection operation was conducted on the intranet. As long as the user's session is active, does it work .

This is the command I am running:

```
robocopy "Source" "Destination" "Log File" /MOV
```

And these are the error messages I'm receiving:

> -Exception Message :Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.
>
> - StackTrace : at system.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> - at system.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String Path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
> - at system.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String Path, Boolean checkHost)
> - at system.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String Path)**

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had slimier issues with mapping network drives over the internet using WebDav in both Explorer and Robocopy: It would work after a user session was started and the username/password was entered, but it wouldn't save the passwords even when asked to, so would stop working at the next logon. The root cause was two-fold:

1) By design on Windows, You can't save webdav credentials to non-local sites (See this [MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/943280))

2) You need to add the URL to the local sites list.

As an attempted fix, try this:

1) Create a Multi String Value at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters called **AuthForwardServerList**

2) Add the URL's you are trying to connect to - using SharePoint, that may be a bit trickier for you to figure out than in my case, but as an example, here's the string I needed to enter:

https://*.[Website].com

http://*.[website].com

*.[Website].com

Optional: while in the WebClient Parameters, you may want to adjust [**FileSizeLimitInByte**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2668751) (To enable longer downloads before timeout) and  [**FileAttributesLimitInBytes**][Can't link more than two URL's, but it's KB912152] (To support large numbers of files in a folder) - I set mine to:

"FileSizeLimitInBytes"=dword:80000000 (Hex)

"FileAttributesLimitInBytes"=dword:00989680 (Hex)

3) Open Internet Explorer, and click Tools, Internet Options

4) Click the Security Tab, then click Local Internet, then sites

5) Click Advance on local internet settings

6) Enter the full https URL of the site, and click Add, then click Close

7)  Click OK, Click OK, then close Internet Explorer

8) Restart the WebClient Service

9)  Open Windows Explorer, and click Map Network Drive

10) Pick a drive letter, Enter the folder as the URL, tick Re-connect at Sign-in, and tick Connect using different Credentials. Click OK.

11) Enter the username and password, and tick the remember my credentials box, and click OK

Hope some of that helps.